# How to open Bugs/PBIs in Visual Studio instead of a web browser when connecting to Azure DevOps Service?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020, azure-devops-services

I want to implement Team Foundation Server (now known as Azure DevOps Server) for source control and issue tracking. I have only used the on-premises solution previously. For this particular use case, it would be beneficial to have it hosted in the cloud.

I have deployed a VSTS/Azure DevOps **Services** cloud solution (as opposed to an on-premises TFS/Azure DevOps **Server** solution), and it seems to have all of the functionality I am used to with the web portal, except there seems to be no direct integration/plugin for Visual Studio.

I can connect Team Explorer to it and query the work items for a basic listing (as shown in the screenshot below) - but if I double click a work item, or if I click <kbd>New Work Item</kbd>, it opens in the web browser, not within Visual Studio.

Is this expected behaviour for VSTS/DevOps Services? Do I need an on-premises installation just to get Visual Studio integration or am I missing something? I would like to use their cloud solution as it has a lot of benefits for this particular use-case.

[image]

Which opens this:

[image]

Instead of this (below screenshot taken from the web):

[image]

Any help is much appreciated! I am hoping to get something up and running ASAP, and would rather not have to install & configure a full on-premises solution in the cloud myself. Letting Microsoft handle it is perfect.

It seems odd that there's no Visual Studio support/integration. I have tried on 2 different machines. I have connected one machine which is running Visual Studio 2017 Professional and the other has VS 2019 Professional. Both open and create work items in the web browser instead of within VS. But VSTS/DevOps Services does seem to have all of the other features of TFS/DevOps Server, as far as I can see.

The web portal is great for other stakeholders, but as a developer I like working directly within Visual Studio. In an on-premises installation you get both. Is there any way to do this on a cloud installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need [set the Work Items experience in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/set-work-item-experience-vs?view=azure-devops), then we can create new work item in the visual studio.

Steps:

Tools->work items->General->change the option Landing page.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Amazing; thank you so much for the prompt reply - this is exactly the option I am looking for! Thank you once again!